# SQL SERVER 2005 And Or

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
WHERE 
( (T1.C3-T2.C3<>0 ) 
And (CASE WHEN T1.C4 <> T2.C4 THEN 'Changed' END) )
OR 
( (T1.C5-T2.C5<>0 )
And (T1.C6-T2.C6<>0) )
```

This is giving me an error ->

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

What is wrong with this statement??

Comment: Solution is -> SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
WHERE 
( (T1.C3-T2.C3<>0 ) 
And (CASE WHEN T1.C4 <> T2.C4 THEN 1 END) = 1 )
OR 
( (T1.C5-T2.C5<>0 )
And (T1.C6-T2.C6<>0) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your Case statement in the were clause, the case statement isn't compared to any value.

I would suggest moving your case statement into the select statement, or making sure you have a value to compare the case statement to.

ie:

```
declare @Changed nvarchar(50) = 'Changed'
```

in the where clause:

```
@Changed = (CASE WHEN T1.C4 <> T2.C4 THEN 'Changed' END) )
```

Comment: In my select statement i am saving this CASE comparison in another column.. the statement is SELECT T1.*, CASE WHEN T1.C4 <> T2.C4 THEN 'Changed' END AS C10 FROM T1 .. WHERE condition.. Motive is -> i have to do this comparison and save the comparison as 'Changed'

Comment: got it. ill write as AND (CASE WHEN T1.C4 <> T2.C4 THEN 1 END) = 1 i guess that should solve it.

Comment: @rahul shukla that is indeed what I meant with you have to compare it against something.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the cause:

```
And (CASE WHEN T1.C4 <> T2.C4 THEN 'Changed' END) )
```

You are doing an `AND` on something that can return `Changed`, which is not a boolean value.

Comment: thats dumb!! i copied it blindly from select statement in my query.. Thanks!!